# Get top 10 items RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android, flatmap

I am using RxJava to get list of Posts from JSONplaceholder api.

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

I want to take only the top 10 from the list and save in the data base.

I am aware I need to use take operator but cannot figure out how to use that with concatMap.

Here is what I have already.

```
private fun loadPosts(){
        subscription = Observable.fromCallable { postDao.all }
                .concatMap { dbPostList ->
                    postApi.getPosts().concatMap { apiPostList -> 
//HERE i ONLY WANT TO TAKE 10 ITEMS AND SAVE IT (HOW CAN I USE TAKE OPERATOR HERE)
                        postDao.insertAll(*apiPostList.toTypedArray())
                        Observable.just(apiPostList)
                    }
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnSubscribe { onRetrievePostListStart() }
                .doOnTerminate { onRetrievePostListFinish() }
                .subscribe(
                        { result -> onRetrievePostListSuccess(result) },
                        { onRetrievePostListError() }
                )
}
```

Below code I tried and it does not work as expected.

```
postApi.getPosts()
        .take(10) // DOES NOT WORK
        .concatMap { apiPostList -> 
            postDao.insertAll(*apiPostList.toTypedArray())
            Observable.just(apiPostList)
        }
```

Comment: i think the takewhile operator was made just for this

Answer (score 1):

`getPosts()` returns a list. To use `take(10)` in your case you'd have to emit each element of the list individual. However, since you emit the entire list in one go, it is as if `take(10)` is trying to take 10 lists of posts rather than 10 posts.

I can think of 2 ways to fix this. You can convert the list to and observable like:

```
postApi.getPosts()
      .flatMap { Observable.fromIterable(it) }
      .take(10)
      .toList()
```

Emit each item of the list, take 10 of them and collect the results in a list ready for your `concatMap`.

Another option is to manually slice the list:

```
postApi.getPosts()
      .map { it.slice(0 until 10) }
```

Not so rx-ish but still should work.

Careful because both approaches assume there are at least 10 items in the list.

Comment: Hello @Fred, cannot find flatMapObservable. could you modify my code accordingly. I am pretty new to rxjava

Comment: sorry for some reason thought `getPosts` was returning a single. In this case you can just use `flatMap`

Comment: Can you give an example please how to use FlatMap with Take

Comment: That's exactly what I posted

Comment: hello Fred
when i tried it this is what i get
Type mismatch.
Required:
((List<PostEntity>) → Publisher<out (???..???)>!)!
Found:
(List<PostEntity>) → Observable<PostEntity!>!

Comment: this is my code
postsService.getPosts()
            .flatMap {  Observable.fromIterable(it) }
            .take(10)
            .toList()

Comment: This works fine for me. Where do you have this? Could you please post the code for `getPosts`? I don't get why suddenly it complains about a `Publisher`.